# Get all numeric before first Alpha in PHP String

Tags: php, regex, string, yii2, numeric

I'm trying to get all numeric before **space/alpha** in PHP string.

**Example**:

```
<?php
//string
$firstStr = '12 Car';
$secondStr = '412 8all';
$thirdStr = '100Pen';

//result I need
firstStr = 12
SecondStr = 412 
thirdStr = 100
```

**How do I can get all the number of a string just like example above?**

I've an idea to get the position of first **Alpha**, then get all numeric before that position.
I've successfully get the position using

```
preg_match('~[a-z]~i', $value, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

But I'm not done yet to get the numeric before the posisition.

#### How do I can do that, or anybody know how to fix my idea?

Anyhelp will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use regex for strings like the examples you've shown, or any functions at all for that matter. You can just cast them to ints.

```
$number = (int) $firstStr;  // etc.
```

[The PHP rules for string conversion to number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) will handle it for you.

However, because of those rules, there are some other types of strings that this won't work for. For example, `'-12 Car'` or `'412e2 8all'`.

---

If you do use a regex, be sure to anchor it to the beginning of the string with `^` or it will match digits anywhere in the string as the other regex answers here do.

```
preg_match('/^\d+/', $string, $match);
$number = $match[0] ?? '';
```

Comment: Both of them work well, I think, I'll just use your first suggestion without regex. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extremely hackish approach that will work in most situations:

```
$s = "1001BigHairyCamels";
$n = intval($s);
$my_number = str_replace($n, '', $s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = '100Pen';
if (preg_match('~(\d+)[ a-zA-Z]~', $input, $m)) {
  echo $m[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will do the job!

```
<?php
function getInt($str){
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    return $matches[0][0];
}
$firstStr = '12 Car';
$secondStr = '412 8all';
$thirdStr = '100Pen';
echo 'firstStr = '.getInt($firstStr).'<br>';
echo 'secondStr = '.getInt($secondStr).'<br>';
echo 'thirdStr = '.getInt($thirdStr);
?>
```